# How can I export an action group to an ARM template in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Currently I have an availability test that pings an API to check if it's responsive. If it is down, I send an email to myself via an action group.

What I want to do is create an ARM template for this, so new projects in the future can behave the same way...by emailing me if the API is down.

I was able to export the availability test to JSON, but I cannot find where to export the action group to JSON so I can set up an ARM template. How would I do this? Is it even possible or does it need to be done manually?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups-create-resource-manager-template

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yeah, I've been looking at that to do it manually, but my question is related to how export them if I already have it created.

Comment: go to the resource group they are in and hit the `automation template` button or whatever it is called nowadays? if they are not there you can use resource.azure.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it's **not supporting for exporting Action Groups as ARM Templates** now. You could vote up this [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/231545-diagnostics-and-monitoring/suggestions/34662361-add-support-for-exporting-arm-templates) to promote this feature to achieve.

Also, as 4c74356b41 said, when you [create an action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups-create-resource-manager-template) with a Resource Manager template, you could go to `your_resource_group` and click `Show hidden types` you may get the resource which you created before.

Then click `your_Action_Group` and `Export template`, `download` it.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This works, thank you. Just a note the resource group it was under for me was: Default-ActivityLogAlerts for anyone reading in the future. All I did was search all resources, found the action group and was able to export it just like the template above.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, thank you!